# Joi require at least one of a group of keys when a specific key exists

Tags: javascript, joi

Given the example:

```
Joi.object({
  a: Joi.string(),
  b: Joi.string(),
  c: Joi.string(),
})
```

I want that when key A is filled, keys B and C are required at least one of them:

```
{ a: 'foo', b: 'bar' } //success
```

```
{ a: 'foo', c: 'bar' } //success
```

```
{ a: 'foo' } #error
```

Comment: And if key A is not filled? Which keys are then required?

Answer (score 1):

You can require a [minimum](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.3.0#objectminlimit) count of keys on the object.

```
Joi.object({
  a: Joi.string(),
  b: Joi.string(),
  c: Joi.string(),
}).min(1)
```